# Using Split and join together in Ansible template file

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, django-templates, jinja2

I want to use hostnames of a group in ansible inventory in a template bash script file.
This is my inventory:

```ini
[group_srv]
srv1.co.company
srv2.co.company
srv3.co.company
```

This is that I wrote in `script.sh.j2`

```bash
for i in '{{ groups['group_srv'][0:3].split('.')[0] | join(' ') }}' ; do
  echo $i
done
```

This is my desired output, but I cannot use `split()` and `join()` together.

```
for i in  'srv1' 'srv2' 'srv3'; do
  echo $i
done
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible provides a [magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) containing the short name for each server in your inventory (i.e. the first string before the first dot): `inventory_hostname_short`

You can access all servers vars in an other magic var: `hostvars`

You can use the [`map` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html) to:

1. extract values for a list of keys inside a dict (e.g. the relevant hosts for your group in `hostvars`)
2. select a single key in a list of dictionaries (e.g. the short inventory name in each extracted server vars).

Those two operations can actually be done at once at extraction time.

Putting it all together:

```
for i in '{{ groups['group_srv'] | map('extract', hostvars) | map(attribute='inventory_hostname_short') | join("' '") }}' ; do
  echo $i
done
```

Which can be shortened as

```
for i in '{{ groups['group_srv'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname_short') | join("' '") }}' ; do
  echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration below does the job

```yaml
short_0_3: "{{ groups.group_srv[0:3]|
               map('split', '.')|
               map('first')|
               join(' ') }}"
```

The next option is the extraction of the variable *inventory_hostname_short*

```yaml
short_0_3: "{{ groups.group_srv[0:3]|
               map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname_short')|
               join(' ') }}"
```

Both options give

```yaml
short_0_3: srv1 srv2 srv3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    short_0_3: "{{ groups.group_srv[0:3]|
                   map('split', '.')|
                   map('first')|
                   join(' ') }}"
  tasks:
    - block:
        - shell: "for i in {{ short_0_3 }}; do echo $i; done"
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: out.stdout_lines
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[group_srv]
srv1.co.company
srv2.co.company
srv3.co.company
srv4.co.company
srv5.co.company
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jinja2 loop you can use filters.
`{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}` adds a white space after every element except the last one.

```yaml
for i in {% for host in groups['group_srv'] %}'{{ host.split('.')[0] }}'{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}{% endfor %} ; do
  echo $i
done
```

Result:

```yaml
for i in 'test-001' 'test-002' ; do
  echo $i
done
```